# Как присвоить переменной значение из таблицы БД?

Tags: php, mysql

У меня есть таблица info, где всего одна строка: `id = 1, year = 2000`. Я хочу переменной `$info` присвоить значение 2000.

Делаю так:

```
$database = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'db');

function get_info($database) {
    $sql = "SELECT info.year FROM `info` WHERE id = 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($database, $sql);
    $info = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    return $info;
}

$info = get_info($database);
```

Теперь хочу вывести в HTML `$info['year']`, но выдает пустое значение. Как можно решить проблему?

Comment: Смотри что в `print_r($info);` Там судя по всему массив массивов, так как юзается `fetchAll` И тогда - `$info[0]['year']`.

Comment: Спасибо, работает!

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM post WHERE id=1",$db);
```